# Remove rows from a pandas dataframe at random without shuffling dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, random

I've got a dataset which needs to omit a few rows whilst preserving the order of the rows. My idea was to use a mask with a random number between `0` and the length of my dataset but I'm not sure how to setup a mask without shuffling the rows around i.e. a method similar to sampling a dataset.

Example: Dataset has 5 rows and 2 columns and I would like to remove a row at random.

```
Col1  Col2
   A     1
   B     2 
   C     5     
   D     4
   E     0
```

transforms to:

```
Col1  Col2
   A     1
   B     2   
   D     4
   E     0
```

with the third row (`Col1='C'`) omitted by a random choice.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The following should work for you. Here I sample `remove_n` random row_ids from `df`'s index. After that `df.drop` removes those rows from the data frame and returns the new subset of the old data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)

remove_n = 1
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4], "b":[5,6,7,8]})
drop_indices = np.random.choice(df.index, remove_n, replace=False)
df_subset = df.drop(drop_indices)
```

DataFrame `df`:

```
    a   b
0   1   5
1   2   6
2   3   7
3   4   8
```

DataFrame `df_subset`:

```
    a   b
0   1   5
1   2   6
3   4   8
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. A slight correction to your solution is to let the dataframe equal the dropped indices dataframe i.e. last line is `df =  df.drop(drop_indices)`. It works well after this change.

Comment: @Black, thanks for the feedback. I admit that my first version was not as clear as it could be. I have now explicitly saved the output of `df.drop` to a variable.

Comment: You could also use `df = df.drop(numpy.random.randint(number_of_rows_you_want_to_drop)`. This preserves the order but assumes an integer index.

Comment: @mnky9800n randint does replacement=True, so that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

We could `sample` the frame and sort the index afterwards.

```py
n_remove = 2
df1 = df.sample(n=len(df)-n_remove).sort_index()
```

Another way is to sort the randomly chosen indices and filter.

```py
keep_idx = np.random.default_rng().choice(len(df), replace=False, size=len(df)-n_remove)
keep_idx.sort()

df1 = df.take(keep_idx)
```

[image: res]