# "Drop random rows" from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe, how can I drop a **random subset** of rows that **obey a condition**?

In other words, if I have a Pandas dataframe with a `Label` column, I'd like to drop 50% (or some other percentage) of rows where `Label == 1`, but keep all of the rest:

```
Label A     ->    Label A
0     1           0     1
0     2           0     2
0     3           0     3
1     10          1     11
1     11          1     12
1     12
1     13
```

I'd love to know the simplest and most pythonic/panda-ish way of doing this!

---

Edit: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556942/pandas-remove-rows-at-random-without-shuffling-dataset) provides part of an answer, but it only talks about dropping rows by index, disregarding the row values. I'd still like to know how to drop only from rows that are labeled a certain way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `frac` argument

```
df.sample(frac=.5)
```

If you define the amount you want to drop in a variable `n`

```
n = .5
df.sample(frac=1 - n)
```

To include the condition, use `drop`

```
df.drop(df.query('Label == 1').sample(frac=.5).index)

   Label   A
0      0   1
1      0   2
2      0   3
4      1  11
6      1  13
```

Answer (score 5):

Using **`drop`** with **`sample`**

```
df.drop(df[df.Label.eq(1)].sample(2).index)

   Label   A
0      0   1
1      0   2
2      0   3
3      1  10
5      1  12
```

Comment: I would recommend using the method in piRSquared answer, as it is better at deciding the percentage to drop