# How to delete specific number of random rows in Pandas dataframe based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete specific 'n' number of rows from a dataframe, where the rows to be deleted are chosen randomly. Also, it must select the rows based on a condition on particular column values.

For example, my dataframe is as below:

```
C1    C2    C3
1     0     a
2     1     b
3     0     c
4     0     d
5     0     e
6     1     f
7     1     g
8     1     h
9     0     i
```

Now, I want to remove `n=2` rows randomly, that has a condition where `C2==1`.

The resultant frame can be as below:

```
C1    C2    C3
1     0     a
3     0     c
4     0     d
5     0     e
6     1     f
8     1     h
9     0     i
```

or

```
C1    C2    C3
1     0     a
2     1     b
3     0     c
4     0     d
5     0     e
7     1     g
9     0     i
```

or maybe other possibles too.
The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556942/pandas-remove-rows-at-random-without-shuffling-dataset) dows shows to remove 'n' sentences randomly, but it doesn't include providding the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) for random rows, last use `drop`:

```
N = 2
df1 = df.drop(df[df['C2'].eq(1)].sample(N).index)
print (df1)
   C1  C2 C3
0   1   0  a
1   2   1  b
2   3   0  c
3   4   0  d
4   5   0  e
6   7   1  g
8   9   0  i
```

Or use `np.random.choice` for random index values:

```
df = df.drop(np.random.choice(df.index[df['C2'].eq(1)], N))
```

Comment: Tried both, `df1 = df.drop(df[df['C2'].eq(1)].sample(N).index)` works fine. but `df = df.drop(np.random.choice(df.index[df['C2'].eq(1)], N))` doesn't.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa - Can you explain more?

Comment: I have total of 89609 columns, with a particular column with values of 0 and 1. 
My inention was to downsample the data. The number of rows with C2==0 was 73462, and C2==1 was 16147. I tried to remove (73462-16147)=> 57315 rows randomly, where C2==0. While using `df1 = df.drop(df[df['C2'].eq(1)].sample(N).index)`, I got 32294 rows, which is what exacly I want, and the data looks fine. But with `df.drop(np.random.choice(df.index[df['C2'].eq(1)], N))`, I get 49667 rows.

Comment: Anyways, I have upvoted your answer. Given only, the 1st part of the answer, I shall accept it as well.